# Quote Payment in Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, quote

I want to getAddtional infomation from quote payment by order id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use`getAdditionalInformation()` method to get AdditionalInformation by order id

```
$orderId = 1148;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
$quoteid=$order->getQuoteId();
$quotedata=$objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($quoteid);
$AdditionalInformation=$quotedata->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
```

**NOTE: CODE TESTED**